# Nagios escalation and wildcards

Tags: linux, monitoring, nagios

I've problems configuring escalations on nagios. I'm getting a the following error:

```
Error: Could not expand hostgroups and/or hosts specified in host escalation (config file '/usr/local/nagios/etc/objects/escalations.cfg', starting on line 11)
   Error processing object config files!
```

The escalations.cfg file looks as follow:

```
define hostescalation{
  host_name    *
  contact_groups    admins
  first_notification  1
  last_notification  3
  notification_interval  30
  escalation_period  24x7
  escalation_options  d,u
  }

define hostescalation{
  host_name    *
  contact_groups    suppliers
  first_notification  4
  last_notification  6
  notification_interval  60
  escalation_period  24x7
  escalation_options  d,u
  }

define serviceescalation{
  host_name    script.myprojects
  service_description  HTTP
  first_notification  1
  last_notification  3
  notification_interval  30
  contact_groups    admins
  }

define serviceescalation{
  host_name    script.myprojects
  service_description  HTTP
  first_notification  4
  last_notification  6
  notification_interval  60
  contact_groups    suppliers
  }
```

What I want is, get all hostgroups and their members using the wildcard (*). This is not working. Can anyone provide any solution? Am I missing any definition and if so, where/how to put this definition?

Thanks!

Comment: `nagios -V`? `nagios -v /path/to/nagios.cfg`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear whether you can use wildcards in this object definition.  But assuming you *can*, make sure you have `use_regexp_matching=0` per this Nagios doc:
http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/configmain.html#use_regexp_matching

Comment: I've checked nagios.cfg. In this file 2 directives are availiable concerning to regexp_matching..

`use_regexp_matching=1`

`use_true_regexp_matching=0`

Should the `use_true_regexp_matching=0 be changed to 1? I didn't know about regexp matching on nagios at all. Thanks!

Comment: http://nagios.sourceforge.net/docs/3_0/objecttricks.html

Comment: you  need it set to "0"